# SharePoint Error "The list cannot be displayed in Datasheet View"

Tags: sharepoint

How to fix this error in SharePoint:

> "The list cannot be displayed in
>   Datasheet view. A datasheet component
>   compatible with Windows SharePoint
>   Services is not installed, your
>   browser does not support ActiveX
>   controls, or support for ActiveX
>   controls

It started to days ago, for apparently no reason. ActiveX is enabled on this site and I had everything working fine so far. Not sure what went wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: Is this happening just for you, or for all users? On just this Datasheet view, of for all Datasheets?

Comment: Error occurs only for me, on all Datasheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... from IE check out your Internet Options, and look under 'Programs'->'Manage Add-Ons'

When I had this problem it was because an add-on was missing or disabled... * thinks * "Microsoft Office List 12.0" or something.

Comment: I have Microsoft Office List 11.0 enabled - still not working and no idea how to fix it. The most recent thing I downloaded was Java, you think might have something to do with that?

Comment: Hmmm... no idea then :(
Just to be thorough; what version of Office? What SP?

Comment: Hmmm... then I'm not too sure. Best I can offer is parroting this: http://codeforfuture.com/2009/04/22/solutions-sharepoint-datasheet-view-doesnt-work/

Comment: Disabling Microsoft Office List 12.0 and then enabling it again worked for me. IE 8 32-bit with Office 2010 32-bit on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the below in SharePoint 2010.

> The Standard View of your list is being displayed because your browser
>   does not support running ActiveX controls.

Turns out the site (master page) was being rendered in IE9 mode and the datasheet supports only up to IE8.

The datasheet mode can be used temporarily by switching the `Document mode` and the `User agent string` both to IE 8, or permanently by using the meta tag `X-UA-Compatible` `IE=8`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is  known issue and you have to install the hotfix provided by Microsoft.

The issue is addressed in the below specified link along with the URL for the hotfix.

http://www.himmeltech.com/blog/fix-for-datasheet-view-issue-error-in-sharepoint-2010/

Let me know whether the suggested solution fixes your issue

Comment: It is recommended not only to provide a link as answer, but summarizing the important contents. that way the answer stays complete even if the linked content vanishes ;)

Answer (score 2):

Please install below data connectivity component to resolve this issue.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

This link helped me and it worked fine. Our environment was Windows 7 64bit and MS office 64bit as well, after installing this connectivity tools, user had a option edit the data sheet view in sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue after updating to Office 365 but remaining with IE 11 and Sharepoint 2010.

Issue:

> using a 64-bit version of Office with a 32-bit version of IE

Reference: [Technet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/seanearp/2010/07/26/resolution-to-missing-datasheet-view-with-64-bit-versions-of-office/)

**Resolution:** Installed [2007 Office System Driver: Data
   Connectivity  Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734)

Comment: This worked for us.  In our case, we had users running Office 2013 Professional in conjunction with SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a client/browser problem.. do you have Microsoft Office installed? Did you change security settings in Internet Explorer?

Comment: Checked all: settings; upgraded my browser; ms office. Everything is fine, except for my Datasheet view. I am the admin on that site, and is only not working for me, the other users are fine.

Answer (score 0):

My environment is SP2010 enterprise and after trying several solutions, I realized that the user that could not see the views in Datasheet style was because did not have installed "Microsoft Access" that is required when you are using views in datasheet style. So the solution for me was to upgrade that specific user from Office Standard to Office Professional

Answer (score 0):

For me, I performed the following and it worked for me:

1. Open Control Panel and open Programs and Features
2. Find your instance of Microsoft Office and select it
3. Click change at the top
4. On the dialog that comes up, click Add or Remove Features and then continue
5. Make sure Microsoft Access Web Datasheet Component is installed under Office Tools/Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Support
6. Even if it is showing as installed, click Continue.
7. Let everything install, close any office programs out, then try again

These steps worked for me.